# error: Task :publishMavenPublicationToNexusRepository FAILED

Tags: repository, devops, nexus, snapshot, artifact

Here is the error i am getting while deploying artifacts to nexus repository :
Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.example:java-maven-app:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata
com.example:java-maven-app:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to nexus-snapshots (http://64.227.148.173:8081/repository/maven
-snapshots/): authentication failed for http://64.227.148.173:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/com/example/java-maven-app/1.1.0-SN
APSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, status: 401 Unauthorized [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKXJU.png)enter code here

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-maven-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- to handle any Java version mismatch, add the following configuration for maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://64.227.148.173:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I had added all the required code in pom.xml file and made all changes but getting this error please help me with solving this issue.

Comment: Please re-edit your question and provide the ```build.gradle``` so the community can see your configuration to be able to help. Use this page to format correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

That's a 401 error. Login credentials were not sent, or invalid login credentials were sent. You need to ensure the settings.xml file has a "server" section that matches the ID shown in that message after "from/to", which in your case is "nexus-snapshots".  That should hold the login credentials needed to access Nexus Repo.

```
  <settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <username>userid</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
   </servers>
...
  </settings>
```